# googleカレンダーから特定の予定のみを取得する方法について

Tags: python, python3, google-calendar-api

googleカレンダーAPIを用いて、特定時間のカレンダーを取得するコードを作成したのですが指定時間の予定ではなく、翌日以降の予定を拾ってしまいます。
指定日時のデータを取得する方法はあるでしょうか。

**・コード**

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin='2021-07-27T10:00:00.000000Z',
                                        maxResults=1, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
   print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
   start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
   print(start, event['summary'])
```

**・想定結果**

```
2021-07-27T10:00:00+09:00 カレンダー取得テスト
```

**・実際の結果**

```
2021-07-28T16:00:00+09:00 別の予定
```

上記のように27日10時指定をした場合にその時間の予定ではなく翌日28日の一番初めの予定が拾われてきてしまう形になります。
TimeMinを前日(ここでは26日)に指定すると27日の予定は拾ってくれるのですが、27日の一番初めの予定となるため別の予定を取得してしまいます。

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list
googleの説明を見たのですが、解決できずご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: timeMinで指定してる値はZで終わっているためUTCの2021-07-27 10:00で、これはJSTだと2021-07-27 19:00になるためでは？

Comment: 上でいただいた通り時間のズレが原因でした。
9時間ずらしで判別はできたのですが、予定が別の予定の時間と被っていると先の時間に入っている予定が優先されるようでした。